# Create new user registration with one model er extended to another model Profile

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-admin

The problem is that I extended the User model to a Profile model and the Profile model has a ManyToMany field and I want to create a user registry but I do not know how to do it, I'm giving the ManyToMany relationship error.

These are my models.

```
class Categoria(models.Model):#Son las categorias a la que pertenecen los negocios(aplican pa todos)

name   = models.CharField(max_length=50)
slug   = models.SlugField(editable=False)
imagen = fields.ImageField(upload_to = 'categorias',null=True,blank=True,dependencies=[
    FileDependency(processor=ImageProcessor(
        format='JPEG', scale={'max_width': 200, 'max_height': 150}))
])

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.id:
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
    super(Categoria, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name

class Perfil(models.Model):#Este es el perfil del usuario(solo existe uno por cada usuario)
user           = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile') 
nombre_negocio = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
encargado      = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True,blank=True)
imagen         = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'perfiles',null=True,blank=True)
direccion      = models.CharField(max_length=100)
telefono       = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=0,null=True,blank=True)
email          = models.EmailField()
category       = models.ManyToManyField(Categoria)
inicio         = models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True)
final          = models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True)
lat            = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True,blank=True)
lng            = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True,blank=True)


def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.id:
        self.slug = slugify(self.nombre_negocio)
    super(Perfil, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.nombre_negocio
```

This is the form I am creating.

```
class UserForm(UserCreationForm):

negocio   = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
encargado = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
imagen    = forms.ImageField()
direccion = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
telefono  = forms.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=0)
email     = forms.EmailField()
#categoria = forms.ManyToManyField(categoria)
lat       = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
lng       = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
```

I do not know what I'm doing wrong because the categoría field is giving me error.

Answer (score 2):

There's no such thing as a `forms.ManyToManyField`, maybe try using [`forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/fields/#modelmultiplechoicefield).

So instead of

```
categoria = forms.ManyToManyField(categoria)
```

try

```
categoria = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Categoria.objects.all())
```